# How do I darken shadows from a shadow catcher in the compositor?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, shadows, render-layers, shadowcatcher

[image]

I am working on a shot of a car sitting in a plane integrated into a video I shoot.

When I rendered the image sequence I separated the shadow from the car (when I was rendering the Car itself I disabled the Shadow catcher plane and vice versa) to give me more flexibility in compositing. Then I imported the shadow sequence and the car sequence in After effects.
When I am trying to darken the shadows more using curves the shadow is not affected with any change. I imported the sequence in blender compositor but the same thing happens.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue?

[image: strong text]

Comment: Related to Blender - please give as screenshot or better simplified blend file of composition via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to see setup. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your reply I uploaded the file

Comment: What format did you use to export the shadow?

Comment: I tried PNG and EXR but both are not working

Comment: Are you multiplying the shadow as transfer mode?

Comment: No i didn't apply any blending mode
it is just an alpha channel in normal blending mode placed on top of the footage

Comment: Have you tried converter > separate RGBA , then modify your channels separately , then combine with converter > combine RGBA?

Comment: No I have not tried this actually
but i think the concept itself is weird
you can imagine this shadow layer as a normal rendered imaged but the shadows are not affected by any color correction effect either in blender or after effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to export the shadow pass. If you don't wanna do this, create a "Shadow pass" like with a white background so curve have something between black and white and not only black and alpha. after that you should be able to edit the shadow and add this to your scene using a Multiply blend mode.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you multiply the pixel values by let's say 0.5, all white/grey areas will effect the color values of the clip. Why do you think this is one good approach?

Comment: I think this is a very smart way it works perfectly with me
thank you for your response

Comment: @Emir May I ask you for more details? I mean whole node tree - how to combine with footage? I also got "footage" influnced (brighter/darker) when I changed RGB Curvature. Thank you

Comment: @brockmann This was just an example about how to manipulate a shadow with alpha, obviously you set the curve as in the image you will get balck, grey and white, you need to manipulate the curve, probrably close to the center. things that worked for me, I am very sorry if i nsulted you with this answer, that was not my intention. just trying to help.

Comment: @vklidu if you render this you can use something like After effect and combine this with your footage.

Comment: @Emir ussualy I use Alpha Over to mix two images so I pluged footage there, that was wrong, so you use it like this https://imgur.com/gkSE0mp , so 3 nodes needed anyway, right?

Comment: No need to say sorry @Emir... but I still don't get how this might help and especially why this is *correct*, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, you should affect Alpha channel not the RGB values for correct result.

- connect EXR alpha channel to *RGB Curve* node
- to combine image and alpha channel back add **Set Alpha** node

[image]
RGB channels of *Shadow Catcher* probably does not contain any information at all.

Note: for images like PNG (without separate alpha channel listed) you can use **Separate RGB** node.

Comment: Yes, it works 
thank you so much :)

Comment: Yes, of course, I did already I marked the up arrow

Comment: I did that thank you again :)